# GCP bucket reachable in UI but not by gcsfuse in the cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

Hi I want reach some files in a GCP bucket from the cloud shell terminal (for sftp reasons), gcsfuse successfully mounts the father dir and it has all the directories except the one I need, any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions that gcsfuse is using to access the desired files.  There also appears to be the ability to run diagnostics using logging options ... see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#logging

Comment: Are you able to find the desired directory? Did the above github link help you?

Comment: nope, ended up using gsutil cp

Answer (score 3):

In Google Cloud Storage object names ending in a slash(/) represent a directory, and all other object names represent a file. By default directories are not implicitly defined, they exist only if a matching object ending in a slash(/) exists.

Since the usual file system operations like `mkdir` will do the right thing, if someone set up a bucket's structure using only `gcsfuse` then they will not notice anything odd about this. However, if someone uses some other tool to set up objects in Google Cloud Storage (such as the storage browser in the Google Cloud Console), they may notice that not all objects are visible until they create leading directories for them.

For example, let's say someone uploaded an object `demo/start.txt` by choosing the folder upload option in the storage browser section in Google Cloud Console, then mounted it with `gcsfuse`. The file system will initially appear empty, since there is no `demo/` object. However if they subsequently run `mkdir demo`, they will now see a directory named `demo` containing a file named `start.txt`.

To mitigate this issue `gcsfuse` supports a flag called `--implicit-dirs`. When this flag is enabled, name lookup requests use the Google Cloud Storage API's `Objects.list` operation to search for objects that would implicitly define the existence of a directory with the name in question. So, in the example above, a directory named `demo` containing a file `start.txt` would appear.

So in your case I suspect the file you are not able to see is a folder which you have uploaded in Google Cloud Storage bucket. As you have already mounted `gcsfuse` with a directory, if you mount it again using the flag `--implicit-dirs`, it will throw an error. So I would suggest you to unmount the directory by running the following command -

```
fusermount -u /path/to/mount/directory
```

Then mount the directory again by running the following command -

```
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs BUCKET_NAME /path/to/mount/directory
```

You can also create a new directory and mount that directory with gcsfuse without unmounting the existing mounted directory.

Please note that the flag `--implicit-dirs` has some drawbacks. I would recommend you to go through [this github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/7) to get detailed information about it.

Comment: Does this resolve the issue?